# How to get focused textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

HTML code :

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="textboxclass" onclick="input(this.id)" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" class="textboxclass" onclick="input(this.id)" />
<input type="button" id="btn3" class="textboxclass" onclick="input(this.id)" />
<input type="button" id="btn4" class="textboxclass" onclick="input(this.id)" />
```

and Javascript code :

```
function input(e) {
    e = e.charAt(3);
    $(".textboxclass").each(function(index, value) {
        if ($(this).is(':focus')) {
            $(this).val($(this).val() + e);
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
$(this).is(':focus')
```

line is not working but when i set `alert($(this))` it works after that alert

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with that code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. When you click on a textbox, it becomes the focused textbox.

Comment: You can also just use `$(".textboxclass:focus")` to select the focused box.

Comment: `if (document.activeElement.nodeName == "BUTTON") {` is this something you want

Comment: ohh my bad `class="textboxclass"` is not for the button. there is one button like `<input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="input(this.id)">` and there is many textbox like `<input type="textbox" class="textboxclass">` i made mistake

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to append the last character of the ID to the value of the clicked input field. Then Why don't you just do,

```
$(function(){
    $(".textboxclass").click(function(){
      var num = this.id.charAt(3);
      $(this).val($(this).val() + e);
    });
});
```